Encoded script to executed
I am trying to code a script so that it is not readable at a glance, I am performing the following steps:
$expression = Get-Content -Path .\backupsql_v1.0.ps1 -Raw
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($expression)
$b64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
Write-Debug "Base64: $b64"
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "$b64"

But the following error occurs
Program 'powershell.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt line:1 char:1
+ powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "$b64"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "$b64"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

How can I avoid or enlarge the size of the string 32,767 characters?
Or what other method can I use to code a script?
Regards

What are you trying to protect against here? Anyone who can read the command line can trivially recreate the original script in full ...

It seems the max length of the encoded string is 32768 chars (exactly 32kb) - empirically, this is the largest source string (12265 chars) that runs ok $x = "#" + ("a" * 12264); $b64 = [system.convert]::ToBase64String([system.text.encoding]::unicode.getbytes($x)); pwsh -encodedcommand $b64 (if you inspect $b64.Length it's 32768). But per @MathiasR.Jessen this is not a security feature - it's easily reversible by anyone who can google "online base 64 decoder".

Correction - the max source length seems to be 12,265 chars => 32,768 base64 chars  when using the -EncodedCommand parameter with pwsh.exe and 12,257 => 32,668 for powershell.exe

The script contains a username and password that are encrypted, but in the code you can see what the key files are so you could recreate it. I am trying to protect the code a bit more so that it is not so easy to get those keys out.
What other option would there be to encode the script?

Welcome to StackOverflow! I hope you enjoy our community. You can use the comment under your question to know about it. Thanks!
